# ngBindHtml doesn't work with ngSanitize

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a newbie on Angular.js so I know this is too basic question but here looks like only place to find answers to angular.js questions.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="example">
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script>
var example = angular.module("example", ['ngSanitize']);
example.controller("exampleCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.appTitle = "<b>Example Angular App</b>";
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
    <h1 ng-bind-html="appTitle"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I follow the book of Rodrigo Branas(Angular.js Essentials). He just use "parking" word as the name of variable instead of "example".

I don't know if there is update for angular.js etc?

Comment: `angular.min.js` should be top of all angular modules.

Comment: @RahilWazir I've just updated.

Comment: `ng-bind-html` should work now

Comment: @RahilWazir doesn't work.

Comment: Its working fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/rwJkQLycN4Rm0DLB24Fu?p=preview

Comment: @YusufAliBozkır what's the version of your angularjs and sanitize? Cause angular just change ng-bind-html-unsafe to ng-bind-html after 1.2.1. [According to this issue.](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/813)

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang AngularJS v1.2.26

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang I've just realized that that's because of the "<script src="">" I don't know if that is because of version but when I use angularjs' CDNs that works well!

Comment: @YusufAliBozkır So you already solve this problem~? If not, I suggest post your code to plunker or jsfiddle.(include the angular library)

Answer (score 0):

to display items in $scope use :

```
<h1>{{ appTitle }}</h1>
```

checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zn7osxt6/

Comment: That fiddle doesn't show the usage of `ng-bind-html` directive.

Comment: if it is about displaying text why use weird obsolete directive when you can bind everything with simple syntax?

Comment: `ng-bind-html` renders html string into your dom, otherhand `ng-bind` renders plain string.